# Json result only returning 1 row

Tags: jquery, json

For some reason my function only spits out 1 row from my json data.  How can I make this loop? I'm sure I'm missing something simple!

JSON

```
[
    {"id":"3","job_title":"Aircraft Technician","job_description":"","job_qualifications":null,"created_at":"2014-06-02 18:00:32","updated_at":"2014-06-02 18:00:32","industries":"","division_id":"3","industry_job_id":"3"},
    {"id":"4","job_title":"Aircraft Technician 2","job_description":"","job_qualifications":null,"created_at":"2014-06-02 18:18:57","updated_at":"2014-06-02 18:18:57","industries":"","division_id":"3","industry_job_id":"4"}
]
```

JQUERY

```
function getIndustryJobs(data_id, data_option){       
    // alert("data-id:"+data_id+", data-option:"+data_option);
    $.getJSON("{{{ Config::get('app.url') }}}/data/json/"+data_id, function(data) {
        $('#roleList').empty();                                                              
        $.each(data, function(key, val){              
            $('#roleList').append('<option value=' + val.id + '>' + val.job_title + '</option>');
            $('#roleList').listview('refresh');
        });

    });
}
```

HTML

```
  <select id="roleList" name="roleList" multiple="multiple"></select>
```

Comment: I think you should use $('#roleList').listview('refresh'); outside the each method

Comment: Your loop is fine (http://jsfiddle.net/MCmPd/) are you sure your incoming JSON is correctly formatted? And your console window isn't showing an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite likely, it is because you're requesting one row, as I can guess from the URL: `.../data/json/"+data_id`.  Which means if you request for all the rows, your code should work fine. The rest of your code looks good, except for the `refresh` which should be outside the loop as @AnoopJoshi correctly said:

```
function getIndustryJobs(data_option){       
    $.getJSON("{{{ Config::get('app.url') }}}/data/json", function(data) {
        $('#roleList').empty();                                                              
        $.each(data, function(key, val){              
            $('#roleList').append('<option value=' + val.id + '>' + val.job_title + '</option>');
        });
        $('#roleList').listview('refresh');

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this ,it's work, I tired

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var data = JSON.parse('[{"id":"3","job_title":"Aircraft Technician","job_description":"","job_qualifications":null,"created_at":"2014-06-02 18:00:32","updated_at":"2014-06-02 18:00:32","industries":"","division_id":"3","industry_job_id":"3"},{"id":"4","job_title":"Aircraft Technician 2","job_description":"","job_qualifications":null,"created_at":"2014-06-02 18:18:57","updated_at":"2014-06-02 18:18:57","industries":"","division_id":"3","industry_job_id":"4"}]');
            $(data).each(function () {
                $('#roleList').append('<option>' + this.id + this.job_title + '</option>');
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: I knew it was something simple.  Thank you all for your contribution.